# How to create infinite scrolling image container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to create a vertical "infinite" scrolling container for a bunch of images.

This is what I've came out with so far:

```js
$("#container").on("scroll", function(e) {
  if (e.target.scrollHeight - e.target.scrollTop === e.target.clientHeight) {
    $(this).scrollTop(0)
  }
})
```

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 2%;
  top: 2%;
  width: 10%;
  height: 90%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

#container {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;
}

#container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <img class="image" src="https://streamdata.io/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/stack-overflow-orange.png">
  <img class="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcScZ51RNyVfUEnqQECgs-S-lzgCCA64GCIwtcHmvBwGw6hjgPL29A">
  <img class="image" src="https://streamdata.io/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/stack-overflow-orange.png">
  <img class="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcScZ51RNyVfUEnqQECgs-S-lzgCCA64GCIwtcHmvBwGw6hjgPL29A">
  <img class="image" src="https://streamdata.io/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/stack-overflow-orange.png">
  <img class="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcScZ51RNyVfUEnqQECgs-S-lzgCCA64GCIwtcHmvBwGw6hjgPL29A">
  <img class="image" src="https://streamdata.io/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/stack-overflow-orange.png">
</div>
```

I was kind of successful implementing the scroll in one direction but I do not know how to implement the scroll top. Also I got some problems because tbh the `scrollTop(0)` looks pretty jerky and is not working every time as it should.

Comment: Maybe this helps you: >[Infinite horizontal scrolling image loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59980269/infinite-horizontal-scrolling-image-loop)